# Need to add paragraph header to each line in the paragraph for linux text file

Tags: bash, command-line, data-manipulation

(Using Linux) I have many text files that have headers followed by several lines of information. I need to move the header to each line of its "paragraph".

```
Paragraph1Header
P1L1Col1  P1L1Col2
P1L2Col1  P1L2Col2

Paragraph2Header
P2L1Col1  P2L1Col2
P2L2Col1  P2L2Col2
```

To

```
P1L1Col1  Paragraph1Header P1L1Col2
P1L2Col1  Paragraph1Header P1L2Col2
P2L1Col1  Paragraph2Header P2L1Col2
P2L2Col1  Paragraph2Header P2L2Col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the program into file **pr.awk** and run `awk -f pr.awk input.txt`

```
NF == 1 {
    h = $1
    next
}

NF > 1 {
    match($0, "[[:space:]]+")
    i = RSTART + RLENGTH - 1
    fst = substr($0,   1, i)
    rst = substr($0, i+1)
    print fst h " " rst
}
```